# Code works when converting 0.0 to 0, but fails with 1.0?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

Python, version 3.5

I have the following code:

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step

def my_func():
    whole_nums = [float(num) for num in range(0, 100)]
    for x in drange(0.0, 100.01, 0.01):
        if str(x).split('.')[1] == '0':
            x = str(x).split('.')[0]
        else:
            x = round(x, 2)
        print(str(x))
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

the `drange` function loops through given numbers, with a given incremental and yields the numbers. The issue is that I want 0, 1, 2, 3 etc, but it will yield 0.0, 1.0, and so on.

I figured that since I knew the format of those wrong numbers (all other numbers in-between like 0.01, all the way to 99.99 I want) I could just do:

`str(theNumber).split('.')[1]`

(as seen in `my_func`) and if the output was `'0'` then I would know I had a 0.0, 1.0 etc and could fetch the output I wanted with `str(theNumber).split('.')[0]` and of course convert it to an int or whatever.

But! When I execute `my_func`, then the `.split()` solution only works on 0.0, when it reaches 1.0 it just skips the `if` statement and goes into the `else`, printing out 1.0 instead of 1.

The code should run fine without importing anything so feel free to give it a whirl.

### Update

Okay, it seems my approach is fundamentally flawed (see @danils answer) so my question is now: how can I generate the numbers ranging from 0 to 100, in increments of 0.01 while ensuring whole numbers are whole. so

`0, 0.01, ..., 1, 1.01, 1.1, 1.02, ... 99.5, 99.51, ..., 100`

Comment: why not simply compare `round(x)` and `int(x)` to see if its a round number?

Comment: Or better still, use `float.is_integer`.

Comment: See also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never rely on the string representation of floating point integers, because they seldom have an exact representation (approximations lead to precision inaccuracies which throw spanners in the works).

You don't need `str(x)` to `print`, because `print` automatically does that for you.

Furthermore, it seems your `drange` function introduces floating point inaccuracies when generating the next values in step. You could instead use `np.arange` for the range, it supports decimal steps:

```
import numpy as np
out = np.arange(0.0, 100.01, 0.01)
print(out)

array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e-02,   2.00000000e-02, ...,
         9.99800000e+01,   9.99900000e+01,   1.00000000e+02])
```

*Note:* If you don't have `numpy`, you can install it using `pip install numpy`.

And lastly, you could use `float.is_integer` to check if a float is a whole number.

---

```
for x in np.arange(0.0, 100.01, 0.01):
    if x.is_integer():
        x = int(x)
    else:
        x = round(x, 2)

    print(x)
```

This gives you:

```
0
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
...
```

Comment: I implemented your solution, but unfortunately i get the same type of misbehaving. Most likely due to what @Danil Speransky  answered. could you try to run out your example and see if you also get a 1.0 instead of the expected 1?

Comment: @7013145 The problem is due to your `drange` function introducing inaccuracies during addition. I tried the same thing using `np.arange` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @7013145 If you have numpy, you can use my answer. That works.

Comment: Oh snap bro, your edit is working like a charm! Thanks for clarifying my wrong-doings, and for a working solution so easily implementable. Numpy really is a powerful module, im starting to realize.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of floating-point arithmetic. It's not exactly `1.0` what you get, more like `1.0000000000000007`. So `str(x).split('.')[1] == '0000000000000007'`.

```
> import numpy as np
> np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
array([   0. ,    0.1,    0.2, ...,   99.8,   99.9,  100. ])
```

Comment: okay that seems rather problematic for my approach. I assume doing int('000000000000007') would yield a '7' at best?

Answer (score 0):

For a version not involving numpy:

```
import time

def drange(start, stop, step):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        yield r
        r += step

def my_func():
    whole_nums = [float(num) for num in range(0, 100)]
    for x in drange(0.0, 100.01, 0.01):
        x = float(int(x * 100))/100
        if x.is_integer():
            print(int(x))
        else:
            print (x)
        time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_func()
```

Admittedly the truncating function is cheesy.

Comment: Yes, but nonetheless your solution works :) I will opt for the numpy solution, though i am interested if there might be any performance differences in the looping.